# How to get machine name on which node server is running?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node server which serves bundle.js for my React/Redux application. How can I get the machine name in Node server is running and send it to my browser app?

Is there some predefined function, which can solve my use case?

```
import React from 'react'
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from './redux/configureStore'
import App from './components/app'

module.exports = function render(initialState) {
  // Model the initial state
  const store = configureStore(initialState)
  let content = renderToString(
    <Provider store={store} >
       <App />
    </Provider>
  );

const preloadedState = store.getState()

const machineName =  ?

return {content, preloadedState, machineName};
}
```

Comment: mistakingly. I have corrected the tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using Node's `os` module, which has the `hostname()` function which:

> ... returns the hostname of the operating system as a string [[1]](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_hostname)

You should expose and endpoint on the Node server to retrieve this information trough a HTTP request (something like GET /device_name), so the React app can consume it. Like so:

```
const os = require('os')
// ...
router.get('/device_name', (req, res) => {
    res.send({ device_name: os.hostname() });
});
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm package name [computer-name](https://www.npmjs.com/package/computer-name)

Its Usage described below

First Install it with `npm i computer-name`

```
const computerName = require('computer-name')

 computerName()
 //=> My-MacbookPro
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var os = require("os");
var hostname = os.hostname();
```